# list' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, distance

I have used the following code to cluster data (8 different points that have different lengths) into 3 clusters using the Wasserstein distance between data points.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage, ward
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering


data = np.array([[5, 2, 2],[3, 6],[1, 6, 2],[7, 2],[7, 2], [6, 1, 3],[8, 1], [2, 4, 7, 3]])
data
```

First, I used the following code to create a distance matrix and then calculate the distance between data points

```
distance_matrix = np.asarray([
    [wasserstein_distance_function(data[first_index], data[second_index]) 
         for first_index in range(len(data))] 
             for second_index in range(len(data))])

distance_matrix
```

But I face this error for distance_matrix:

```
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Comment: Is `distance_matrix` a 2D numpy array, or a 1D numpy array of lists? i.e. what is the value of `type(distance_matrix)` and `distance_matrix.dtype`?

Comment: @Nick ODell 2-dimensional arrays (8 points, with x-, y-coordinates). The distance matrix is a quadratic matrix that has 0s on the diagonal. This matrix is then passed as a parameter to the fit_predict function of a clustering algorithm. So, the distance matrix calculates the distance between data points.